# Laravel 5.3 - Vue 2 flickering on page reload

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, flicker

Every time I reload my page, in stead of displaying my Vue content, it shows and then quickly dissaperes (flickers).

My app.js file:

```
require('./bootstrap');

var Vue = require('vue');

new Vue({
el: '#root',
data: {
   message: 'Hello world!'
}
});
```

My view:

```
<div id="root">
    <input type="text" v-model="message">
    <p>The value of the input is: @{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

Vue console error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. 
>       (found in root instance)

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: I added it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the `runtime-only` build so you need to provide a render function or pull in the `standalone build`. I'm guessing you are just getting everything up and running, so you will need to decide how you are going to design your app.

If you want to use `blade` templating then you will need the `standalone build`, so you just need to add an alias to your `webpack config` to pull it in (see: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-webpack-official):

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
  }
}
```

Or if you are using `browserify` you need to add the following to `package.json`:

```
"browser": {
  "vue": "vue/dist/vue.common"
}
```

`Laravel 5.4` now does this out of the box (with `Laravel mix`), but it looks like your `5.3` version does not.

If you want to use `.vue` files and build and SPA then you can use the `runtime-only` build and create an `App.vue` file with your layout and mount that instead:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var App  = require('./components/App.vue');

const app = new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

You can check out this answer for more infomation if you want to go down this route: [Updating elements outside of a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373641/updating-elements-outside-of-a-component/42375475#42375475)